# RSS reader that also shows the comments from each blog post

Tags: rss

Can you recommend me a RSS reader that also shows the comments from each blog post?

As now, I did not find it on Google Reader.

Comment: have you subscribed to Slashdot before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know, blog comments are not part of RSS structure. that part will be related with the blogs you've subscribed .

for example, [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/) RSS is for both post and comments . and some like Mashable, you've subscribe its comments separately ([RSS URL](http://mashable.disqus.com/facebook_ceo_interviewed_on_ipo_lawsuit_and_more_video/latest.rss)) if you want to read the site comments.

Answer (score 0):

[liferea](http://liferea.sourceforge.net/) will attempt to pick up the comments associated with a RSS entry.

Comment: there is some equivalent of liferea for Mac or iPhone?

Thanks

Comment: Not a clue. You'll have to ask them.